# how to get the time diff from 1900-01-01T14:30:00.000Z format - mysql?

Tags: mysql, datediff

i have 2 dates and need to find the diff btw them in sql.

```
city       time_out                 time_in
Paris   1900-01-01T14:30:00.000Z    1900-01-01T17:50:00.000Z
```

```
select datediff(time_out - time_in) from trip where city = 'Paris'
```

not working.

Comment: `SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,'1900-01-01T17:50:00.000Z', '1900-01-01T14:30:00.000Z')
` does this work ? you can convert the  seconds to hours /minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `TIMEDIFF` .

In case of days you have to parse the [days also](http://%3C!--%20--%3E%20%3E%20%20%20%20%20CREATE%20tABLE%20trip(city%20varchar(10),time_out%20varchar(24),time_in%20varchar(24))%20%3E%20%20%3E%20%3Cpre%3E%20%3E%20%E2%9C%93%20%3E%20%3C/pre%3E%20%20%3C!--%20--%3E%20%3E%20%20%20%20%20INSERT%20INTO%20trip%20VALUES%20%3E%20%20%20%20%20(%27Paris%27,%20%20%20%271900-01-01T14:30:00.000Z%27,%20%20%20%20%271900-01-01T17:50:00.000Z%27)%20%3E%20%20%3E%20%3Cpre%3E%20%3E%20%E2%9C%93%20%3E%20%3C/pre%3E%20%20%3C!--%20--%3E%20%3E%20%20%20%20%20SELECT%20TIMEDIFF(CAST(time_in%20AS%20DATETIME),CAST(time_out%20AS%20DATETIME))%20TIMEdiffrence%20FROM%20trip%20WHERE%20city%20=%20%27Paris%27%20%3E%20%20%3E%20%3Cpre%3E%20%3E%20%7C%20TIMEdiffrence%20%7C%20%3E%20%7C%20:------------%20%7C%20%3E%20%7C%2003:20:00%20%20%20%20%20%20%7C%20%3E%20%3C/pre%3E%20%20*db%3C%3Efiddle%20%5Bhere%5D(https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2bd173ea11ad7b13ef935cbb32b9ebf1)*)

> ```
> CREATE tABLE trip(city varchar(10),time_out varchar(24),time_in varchar(24))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO trip VALUES
> ('Paris',   '1900-01-01T14:30:00.000Z',    '1900-01-01T17:50:00.000Z')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT TIMEDIFF(CAST(time_in AS DATETIME),CAST(time_out AS DATETIME)) TIMEdiffrence FROM trip WHERE city = 'Paris'
> ```
>
> ```
> | TIMEdiffrence |
> | :------------ |
> | 03:20:00      |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2bd173ea11ad7b13ef935cbb32b9ebf1)*